# Combine check boxes without using if

Tags: c#

I'm making a password generator and I have three check boxes: lowercase, uppercase, and number. Right now I have an IF statement that says:

```
    IF (check1.checked == true & check2.checked == true & check3.checked == true)
       {
           length = Convert.ToInt32(lengthTextBox.Text);
                string password = "";
                int choice;
                Generate gen = new Generate();
                for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
                {
                    choice = rnd.Next(1, 4);
                    if (choice == 1)
                    {
                        password = password + gen.lower();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 2)
                    {
                        password = password + gen.upper();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 3)
                    {
                        password = password + gen.number();
                    }
                }

                passwordTextBox.Text = password;
       }
    Else IF (check1.checked == true & check2.checked == true)
    {
            length = Convert.ToInt32(lengthTextBox.Text);
                string password = "";
                int choice;
                Generate gen = new Generate();
                for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
                {
                    choice = rnd.Next(1, 3);
                    if (choice == 1)
                    {
                        password = password + gen.lower();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 2)
                    {
                        password = password + gen.upper();
                    }
                }

                passwordTextBox.Text = password;
    }
```

and so on. This method is terribly inefficient. I ran into this problem while making a cash register program (10 choices of toppings, check the ones you want, and the program adds the prices together. If you uncheck a topping, the price will be subtracted by that amount.), so I just gave up on it. But now, I am determined to find a way to metaphorically go shopping.

Comment: What do the methods that you're calling do? I appreciate they all contribute to a password, but what specifically do the lowercase and uppercase do? Also, consider using the && operator. It will not pose any increase in efficiency here as this is such a minor scale, but it is good practice to use && or & in relevant scenarios.

Comment: you don't need any of the `== true` in there

Comment: ^ Well spotted. Also the 'Else If' will throw an error at compile time. Have you tested this?

Comment: What is so bad about this code? There are only 3 possible items so the number of possible combinations is only 6. That would mean you would only have 6 if statements. That is not very inefficient as it stands.

Comment: What do you mean by inefficient? If it runs slowly, then the problem is with methods of the Generate class, not with this piece of code. And you cash register problem description doesn't add any information about the problem at all.

Comment: @Nunners But the probability of a developer making a mistake somewhere in there is rather great, what with all of the tedious typing or possibilities for copy/paste errors, and the readability of the code suffers greatly.  It's not easy to tell at a glance, when reading the code, if it's correct or not, and if there is a bug in there, finding it is much more time consuming.

Comment: I'm going to assume that by efficiency, OP is referring to readability (i.e. efficiently written). And I agree, it is terribly inefficient in that sense. It's just a bit unnecessary given the type of alternatives listed below. +1 to OP for striving towards better code.

Comment: It's inefficient in length of code. And @Nunners - with the 'shopping' scenario it's many more possibilities.

Comment: WOW! What was that edit about OP? You just made your code a LOT more "inefficient"!!

Comment: @BogdanVerbenets The OP is telling us that even if for 3 it's not bad - he needs a solution for 10 as well.

Comment: @ispiro - But it's the same If structure. It looks like he's now pulled out the code that from the Generate methods and put them directly into the if statement. I don't advise this at all.

Comment: @DeeMac My comment was answering BogdanVerbenets's assertion that `And you[r] cash register problem description doesn't add any information about the problem at all.`.

Comment: @ispiro - ah right, my fault, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you really need to do here is find a way of making the selection of choice dynamic.  One way of doing this is to create a list of functions in which each function is capable of generating a value.  At the start you populate the list with the relevant functions based on what's checked, and then you can have a single loop that simply chooses one of the functions from that list:

```
List<Func<char>> generators = new List<Func<char>>();
if (lowercaseCheckbox.Checked)
    generators.Add(() => gen.lowercase());

if (uppercaseCheckbox.Checked)
    generators.Add(() => gen.uppercase());

if (numberCheckbox.Checked)
    generators.Add(() => gen.number());

int length = Convert.ToInt32(lengthTextBox.Text);
StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    int choice = random.Next(generators.Count);
    password.Append(generators[choice]());
}
string result = password.ToString();
```

Note that rather than appending characters to a string repeatedly in a loop you should be using a `StringBuilder` to avoid constant re-allocation and copying of the values.

I also suggest using more meaningful names for your `checkbox` variables; it makes the code much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is not really clear what your code does, you seem to be able to call the methods consecutive. So why not do it like this;

```
if (check1.Checked)
   Generate.lowercase();

if (check2.Checked)
   Generate.uppercase();

if (check3.Checked)
   Generate.number();
```

Also you should probably want to use more descriptive names for your controls and variables.

Comment: Based on the OP's updated code snippet, this solution is not valid.

Comment: Answers my cash register problem, but not my generator problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(check1.checked) Generate.lowercase();
if(check2.checked) Generate.uppercase();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what framework you're using and what patterns you have applied, but there are better ways to do this. You could use bit flags and have the check boxes and them together.

```
FlagVariable output = FlagVariable.None;
if( topping1.IsChecked )
{
    output &= FlagVariable.Topping1;
}
if( topping2.IsChecked )
{
    output &= FlagVariable.Topping2;
}
// etc...
```

then later

```
if( output | FlagVariable.Topping1 )
{
    // it has topping 1
}
```

This is pretty efficient and maintainable. You'll still have to write associative code between the check boxes and their corresponding flag value (this is the part that depends on your framework/patterns, because in WPF with MVVM you might be able to avoid a lot of if-then code).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split them up:

```
if (check1.checked) Generate.lowercase();
if (check2.checked) Generate.upperrcase();
if (check3.checked) Generate.number();
```

Logically, there is no between this way and the grouped way.

Answer (score 0):

In case of password generation @Gerald Versluis 's answer, is definetely worth looking at.

In the case of the shopping, where you have flavours. "Checking" off flavours, to later add the price of the ones that are "checked off", it just doesn't scale very well, as you have already realised.
In that case it's better to add flavours, to a list, which then is calculated to a total.

This can be applied to the password generation as well. Where you add different "Password" generators, thereby letting it scale alot better, and use C# great OOP capabilities. The buzz-word here is: `Polymorhism`